# Where is the Z in my Render Layer node in composite?

Tags: interface, compositing-nodes

There is supposed to be a Z in the render layer node

[image]

But it is not appearing for me. Please tell me where I can find it?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.79 **Z** renamed to **Depth**

So, here it is:

[image]

Comment: note: only on the node. In scene > passes it is still Z :(

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if in scene > passes the Z pass is enabled?

[image]

if you disable it, the node doesn't show it

[image]

Comment: You are not right, he has Z-pass on screenshot=)

Comment: Oh, yes, right. At home I can't run 2.79 (old intel card on laptop) so I was using 2.76b... anyway the concept shoudl be the same, if you disable the Z pass, the "depth" output won't be on the node... (bad choice to change the label only on the node...)